# Using reflection on Request crashes w3wp.exe process

Tags: c#, reflection, crash, w3wp

Here is my try to make an object dumper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace Inspector
{
    public static class Inspector
    {
        public static string Inspect(this object o)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            InspectObject(o, sb);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private static void InspectObject(object o, StringBuilder sb)
        {
            Type objType = o.GetType();
            if (objType == typeof(string))
                sb.Append(o.ToString());
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(objType.GetProperties());

                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
                    {
                        object propValue = null;
                        ParameterInfo[] ip = prop.GetIndexParameters();
                        if (ip.Length == 0)
                        {
                            propValue = prop.GetValue(o, null);
                            InspectObject(propValue, sb);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("Exception: {0}", ex.Message));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I am using it to inspect `Request` (`Request.Inspect()`) in HomeController's Index method, w3wp.exe process crashes and try-catch block doesn't do it's job.

What is actually happening? Microsoft says, that only unhandled exceptions crash w3wp.exe, but I am calling `Request.Inspect()` wrapped into parent try-catch block;

Comment: Note that StackOverflow (which is common result of recursion) kill process and can't be caught...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exact type of `Request` you use, so I just read the documentation of the [HttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. If that's not what you are using, at least I can give you an idea of what's happening:

1. the `HttpRequest` class has a property called `RequestContext` of type `RequestContext`, so you call `InspectObject` for that property
2. this `RequestContext` has a property `HttpContext` of type `HttpContextBase`, so you call `InspectObject` for that property
3. this `HttpContextBase` has a property called `Request` of type `HttpRequest` which is the **current request**, and - yes - you call `InspectObject` for that property, starting at 1. again because *it's the same instance*

So this recursion never stops and you fill your call stack until you get a `StackOverflowException`. This kind of exception cannot be handled in your `catch` block because the stack (and with it the whole process) is corrupted already.

---

To solve this you need some kind of recursion detection that tells you if you try to inspect an object that has already been inspected. Then you can stop the recursion at that point.
Alternativly you can stop the recursion at a certain depth. The specific solution depends on what you need all that information for.

Comment: It seems to be true, although `Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request != Request`. I limited the depth to 10 and the process does not crash any more.